# Delete one data in database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can someone help me?

I really have difficulty about deleting an entry from a database using Entity Framework.

Here's my data entity:

```
[Key]
[Column(Order = 0)]
public string TransNo { get; set; }
public int? RowID { get; set; }     
public string ClientName { get; set; }
public string PartsCode { get; set; }
public double OrderQty { get; set; }
public double? Stocks { get; set; }
public double UnitCost { get; set; }
public double? TotalAmount { get; set; }
public DateTime? DeliveryDate { get; set; }
public string PONo { get; set; }
public string InCharge { get; set; }
public DateTime? POReceivedDate { get; set; }
public string SNNo { get; set; }
public string SysPartsCode { get; set; }
public string ItemNo { get; set; }
```

The `TransNo` is the primary key.

Then the `RowID` is a unique parameter.

I will select in a datagridview and press the <kbd>delete</kbd> key on my keyboard. There is no problem with that. The only thing is in deleting. Even if I'm using

```
 .where(m => m.RowID == RowID)
```

When I debugged it, the row that I want to delete is selected. But after saving changes and refreshing the database, all the data that was equal to the `TransNo` of the data that I selected is deleted. I only want is to delete the data that is equal to the data that I selected. So the `Transno` that is primary key is equal to the selected data and also the `rowid` that is unique parameter must also equal to the selected data.

It will really select the specific data but it will delete the whole data that is equal to the `transno`.

Help me please..

UPDATE: I am using this code right now:

```
public void DeleteEachByRowID(string TransNo, int rowId)
{
    var rowtoRemove = this.FindAllPOEntry()
                          .Where(x => x.RowID == rowId)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
    db.POEntryProcess.Remove(rowtoRemove);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: What does your code that is doing the delete look like?

Comment: You can [log the query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx) to see what actually happened on the database.

Comment: it really deleted all the data that is equal to the transno of the data that i selected.

Comment: try add TransNo filtering on where. ex.
this.FindAllPOEntry().Where(x => x.RowID == rowId && x.TransNo == TransNo).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: i already tried it but still the result is the same.